# PDO update not returning variables

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use PDO to update a row in my postgres database.

The form is not sending the variables to the handler file.

I'm not sure where the problem lies, I've been battling with this for a few days.

Form

```
//$maxContent is set and available
//$context_number is set and available
    echo"<form method='post' action='updateSpatialPhoto_handler.php'>";

    $query3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM excavation.contexts_spatial_photographs 
        WHERE contexts_spatial.area_easting = {$_SESSION['area_easting']} 
        AND contexts_spatial.area_northing = {$_SESSION['area_northing']} 
        AND contexts_spatial.context_number = {$_SESSION['context_number']}"); 

//contexts_spatial_photographs
    $query3->execute();

while($r = $query3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
    // for each needed
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='photograph_date' value='".$r->photograph_date."'>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='photograph_number' value='".$r->photograph_number."'>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='primary_shot' value='".$r->primary_shot."'>";

        echo"<input type='hidden' name='maxContext' value='", $maxContext,"'>";
    };

    echo"<input type='submit' value='Update Spatial Photo'>";
echo "</form>";
```

handler

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    //
    include 'connect/connect.php';
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if (!isset($_SESSION['photograph_date'])) {$_SESSION['photograph_date'] = $_POST['photograph_date'];}
    if (!isset($_SESSION['photograph_number'])) {$_SESSION['photograph_number'] = $_POST['photograph_number'];}
    if (!isset($_SESSION['primary_shot'])) {$_SESSION['primary_shot'] = $_POST['primary_shot'];}
    if (!isset($_SESSION['maxContext'])) {$_SESSION['maxContext'] = $_POST['maxContext'];}

    if (isset($_SESSION['photograph_date'])) {$_SESSION['photograph_date'] = $_POST['photograph_date'];}
    if (isset($_SESSION['photograph_number'])) {$_SESSION['photograph_number'] = $_POST['photograph_number'];}
    if (isset($_SESSION['primary_shot'])) {$_SESSION['primary_shot'] = $_POST['primary_shot'];}
    if (isset($_SESSION['maxContext'])) {$_SESSION['maxContext'] = $_POST['maxContext'];}

    //echo "Photograph Date: "; echo $_SESSION['photograph_date']; echo "<br />";
    //echo "Photograph Number: "; echo $_SESSION['photograph_number']; echo "<br />";
    //echo "Primary Shot: "; echo $_SESSION['primary_shot']; echo "<br />";

try {
    $sql3 = "UPDATE excavation.contexts_spatial_photographs SET 
        context_number = :context_number 
        WHERE contexts_spatial_photographs.area_easting = $area_easting
        AND contexts_spatial_photographs.area_northing = $area_northing
        AND contexts_spatial_photographs.context_number = $context_number";

    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql3);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters 
    $stmt2->bindParam(':context_number', $maxContext, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt2->execute(); 

    echo "Record updated successfully in contexts spatial photographs<br />";

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the handler, your using lines like...

```
if (isset($_SESSION['maxContext'])) {$_SESSION['maxContext'] = $_POST['maxContext'];}
```

These are setting the values in the session variables, which is fine.
But in your SQL -

```
 AND contexts_spatial_photographs.context_number = $maxContext";
```

$maxContext doesn't seem to be set anywhere.  This may be the same as the session variables, so you need

```
$maxContext = $_SESSION['maxContext'];
```

or

```
 AND contexts_spatial_photographs.context_number = $_SESSION['maxContext']";
```

Although it would be even better if you use bindParam with them, the same way you use it with `:context_number`.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, $maxContent has already been set. 
The variables which are not being posted are the photograph_date, photograph_number, and primary_shot.

Comment: Just re-reading the Update statement, your including $maxContext as one of the search criteria, and then setting the value to be $maxContext.  Surely this will achieve nothing?!

Comment: ah yes, well spotted, I've edited the code to be $context_number

Comment: One other thing is that once the session variables are set, they won't be picked up as the code says don't bother looking at them if the session variables are already set.